# Grouped cumulative line chart won't stack

Tags: group-by, report-chart

I've built a report showing cumulative sales over time for a 3 year period (YTD, last year and year before last).  I'd like to have the report display a line chart of the cumulative sales with each year stacked/overlaid on each other.  The SF help document (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.chart_line_grouped_cumulative.htm&type=5) suggests this is possible with the image from the document:
[image: help doc stacked line chart]
In this case the example they present is cumulative amount of closed opportunities by day, grouped by month.  The suggestion is that the lines for each month will stack on top of each other.

In my case I get cumulative amounts over time (days or months) but the groupings by year display along the x-axis (could be close date or could be month) like this:

[image: non-stacked line chart]

This chart shows cumulative sales by month for 3 years, but the lines for each year are presented separately, so it's very difficult to compare revenue for each year.  This is in part because the months aren't the same for each year (one starts in June, the others in July, and the ending months are all different).  If they were stacked with months along the x-axis and year showing as different lines, comparisons would be simple.

I also tried to do this by day using CloseDate (which is what we really want) but in that case the year is included so the x-axis spans the entire timeframe in the report.  We considered using the day value (1-365) but then we wouldn't know the dates without a lot of mental gymnastics.

I'd be grateful for any info on if and how to get the lines to stack, or some other solution to get the results we want.

Edit: Just to prove that the cumulative lines CAN stack the way I want, I also ran the report using the numeric day value (1-366) and here's what I got:

[image: Cumulative by day value]

Comment: Given you've achieved this by using the numeric value, have you tried the same approach but pulling out the month value rather than the day of the year?

Comment: Thank you Callum.  Not sure if this is what you mean, but the first chart in the question above is using the "Close Month" option from Salesforce.  Since that's a month value and shouldn't contain a year value, it seems it should stack.  But it doesn't.  I did not try to use the month numeric (1-12) because in the end month isn't a very useful metric for this graph (the current month will be pretty far off for most of the month).  I really want this for days.  I'm mostly trying to understand what's going on here.